# GTest: Generate XML Reports for each Testsuite

Tags: xml, unit-testing, googletest, cppunit, test-reporting

GTest is creating a XML Report file, when the executeable is invoked with
-gtest_output=xml:Name.xml.
The XML File contains a summary of every testsuite.
My question is, is it possible to create a XML Report for each testsuite?

[image: Example of GTest XML Report]

According to the picture, I want to have 6 different XML Reports for each testsuite.
Is this possible?

In CppuTest, it is possible. It does this automatically.

Comment: It is impossible and it is right. Other tools can process result similar to as you like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is a way to put them into separate files, however, you can at least create each file separately using `gtest_output` and `gtest_filter`.

Once you created your tests's executable run it with the following parameters:

```bash
<test_executable> --gtest_output=xml:name1.xml --gtest_filter=TestSuiteName1*
<test_executable> --gtest_output=xml:name2.xml --gtest_filter=TestSuiteName2*
<test_executable> --gtest_output=xml:name3.xml --gtest_filter=TestSuiteName3*
...
```

You can easily write a script to generate these commands for your testsuites.